# Is it ever better to use Berkeleys algorithm over NTP for time synchronization?

Tags: algorithm, time, synchronization, ntp

As the topic states: Is it ever better to use Berkeleys algorithm over NTP for time synchronization?

As I understand it NTP is a robust state of the art algorithm that gives the best accuracy and that Berkeleys algorithm is used for synchronization in internal networks. Couldn't NTP be used in an internal network for the best accuracy and by doing so making Berkeleys algorithm sort of "useless" in that sense.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing anything.

The Berleley algorithm(created in 1989) is used when no machine in an internal network has an accurate time source. It works by a server polling all its clients, then it takes an average of all those times, and then adjusting each client based on that average. Its accuracy is on the order of 20ms.

NTP is a robust, time-tested, up-to-date protocol which has an accuracy on the order of a few milliseconds over the internet, and sub-milliseconds on an internal network.

NTP is the way to go in the present day...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It helped me to sort out my confuses. :)